# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment in Angular 13

Tags: angular

I am working on a full stack project with Angular and spring boot , if I am trying to do update or show details of intervention by id , it's not working and it shows me this error:

ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'intervention-details/2'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'intervention-details/2'
at ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.mjs:2936:16)

Comment: `'intervention-details/{id}'` is missing from your route module.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

i think you must define the path in app-routing.module like that:
-"update-cours/:id"

```js
const routes:Routes=[
  
  {path:"update-cours/:id",component:UpdateCoursComponent}
  
];
```

Comment: I find the solution of the error by correcting the route in the component  not in the routing.module

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32010412)

Answer (score 1):

If you are in same module, you can just call directly from your app-routing module
otherwise you can define it like this

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    component: AuthComponent,
    children: [
      { path: 'login', component: LoginComponent },
      { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
    ],
  },
];
```

here auth is my different module

Answer (score 0):

It's telling you that you don't have this route that match the router , check the router module or send me your full routes.

Answer (score 0):

Like "ich rak" mentioned,
Faced the same issue. routing in (app-routing.module.ts) was okay problem was in app.component.html

```
  <ion-tab-button routerLinkActive="tab-selected" routerLink="/home" tab="home">
      <ion-icon name="list-outline"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Opportunities</ion-label>
   </ion-tab-button>
```

the "tab"="home"> had a different name and that was bringing the error. At least in my case